# Inverting currently seleted items in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa

At the moment I can invert the currently selected items in an NSTableView with:

```
- (IBAction) doSelectInvert:(id) sender
{
    NSIndexSet *set1=[myTable selectedRowIndexes];
    NSMutableIndexSet *set2=[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

    NSUInteger nCount=[myTable numberOfRows];

    for(NSUInteger n=0;n<nCount;n++)
        if(![set1 containsIndex:n]) [set2 addIndex:n];

    [myTable selectRowIndexes:set2 byExtendingSelection:NO];

    [set2 release];
}
```

Is this correct, or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important improvement you can make is to adopt ARC. This will make your code more elegant by removing extra `retain`/`release` calls, and prevent a whole lot of simple errors. It's not fun to track down an extra `release` call that only *sometimes* has detectable symptoms.

Looking at all the `NSMutableIndexSet` methods, there are some more powerful operators, like `-removeIndexes:`, that can save you a bit of work, compared to building up your set one-at-a-time. Finding a way to use them sometimes means "inverting" your thinking a bit — for example, removing items from the set of everything, instead of adding items to an empty set.

```
- (IBAction) doSelectInvert:(id) sender
{
    // start with all rows
    NSRange allRows = NSMakeRange(0, [myTable numberOfRows]);
    NSMutableIndexSet *invertedSelection = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:allRows];

    //then remove the currently selected rows
    [invertedSelection removeIndexes:[myTable selectedRowIndexes]];

    //set the new selection
    [myTable selectRowIndexes:invertedSelection byExtendingSelection:NO];
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I'm quite new to cocoa development and still picking up knowledge like this. I also now understand what ARC is doing, another mystery unlocked!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 variant, based on Vincent's answer and with feedback from @vadian:

```
var selection = IndexSet(integersIn: 0...tableView.numberOfRows)
selection.subtract(tableView.selectedRowIndexes)
tableView.selectRowIndexes(selection, byExtendingSelection: false)
```

Or if you prefer hard to read one liners:

```
 tableView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...tableView.numberOfRows).subtracting(tableView.selectedRowIndexes), byExtendingSelection: false)
```